# JavaSparkContext - jarOfClass or jarOfObject doesnt work

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I am trying to run my spark service against cluster. As it turns out I have to do setJars and set my applicaiton jar in there. If I do it using physical path like following it works
`conf.setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/Sample.jar"});`

but If i try to use JavaSparkContext (or SparkContext) api jarOfClass or jarOfObject it doesnt work. Basically API cant find jar itself.

Following returns empty 
`JavaSparkContext.jarOfObject(this);
JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass())`

Its an excellent API only if it worked! Any one else able to make use of this?

Answer (score 1):

*[I have included example for Scala. I am sure it will work the same way for Java]*

It will work if you do :

`SparkContext.jarOfObject(this.getClass)`

Surprisingly, this works for Scala Object as well as Scala Class.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the app? If you are running it from an IDE or compilation tool such as sbt, then

- the jar is not package when running,
- if you have package it once before, then your `/path/to/jar/Sample.jar` exist, thus giving the hard coded path works, but this is not the .class that the jvm runing your app is using and it cannot find.